# Syntax issue with converting over from wavwrite to audiowrite in octave / matlab

Tags: matlab, octave

In *Octave 3.8.1* I'm able to export a stereo wave file using the command below

```
wavwrite([w1(:) w2(:)],44100,16,'/tmp/testfile.wav');
```

I'm trying to get it to work with audiowrite using octave 4.0 see below but I get a *audiowrite: wrong argument name error*

```
audiowrite('/tmp/testfile2.wav',[w1(:) w2(:) w3(:) w4(:)],44100,16)
```

and

```
audiowrite('/tmp/testfile2.flac',[w1(:) w2(:) w3(:) w4(:)],44100,16)
```

It says audiowrite can have up to 256 channels am I incorrect about this?

Thanks

Comment: Try: `audiowrite('/tmp/testfile2.wav',[w1(:) w2(:) w3(:) w4(:)],44100,'BitsPerSample',16)` or perhaps: `audiowrite('/tmp/testfile2.wav',[w1(:) w2(:) w3(:) w4(:)],44100)`. 16 Bits per sample is default.

Comment: @StewieGriffin thanks that did it

Comment: Ah, this is gross. I just answered this on the octave help-mailinglist. **** crossposting....

Comment: @RickT [Cross-posting should be avoided](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Crossposting). Especially without any link pointing to the other question (in _both_ locations). For others, here is the [question on octave-help list](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-octave/2016-05/msg00008.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
audiowrite('/tmp/testfile2.wav',[w1(:) w2(:) w3(:) w4(:)],44100,'BitsPerSample',16)
```

or

```
audiowrite('/tmp/testfile2.wav',[w1(:) w2(:) w3(:) w4(:)],44100).
```

16 Bits per sample is default. Check out the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Audio-File-Utilities.html) here for more information.